# Binary Tree: Method to return TRUE if all values equal a specific value

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

In Java, I'm working on coding a boolean method that traverses through an entire binary tree for a specific value (e.g. integer value 1) and if all the nodes are that value, the method returns true.

So far, I have the following:

```
public static boolean everything1(IntBTNode root) {
    if (root.data == 1) { 
        everything1(root.left);
        return true;
        everything1(root.right);
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, every line of code after a `return` statement will never be executed. So careful there. Second, if you are going to do it with recursion, I recommend the next:

```
public static boolean everything1(IntBTNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return (root.data == 1) && everything1(node.left) && everything1(root.right)
    }
}
```

1. check if the root (node) is null, if it is, just return `true`.
2. else, check if the root data is 1, short circuited with `&&` because if you get `false` the execution finish there, and you want to check if all the items are `1`
3. check recursively if the value is in the left node
4. check recursively if the value is in the right node

Comment: @EJP actually I'm not sure... At first I thought in false

Answer (score 3):

The logic of your recursive method needs to reflect the way you think, in your native language, of the action the method performs. In your case, everything in a tree is `1` when all of the following conditions are true:

- Node itself is `1`, and
- Everything on the left is `1`, and
- Everything on the right is `1`

It is also trivially true when the node itself is `null`, which is your base case.

When you start implementing your recursive method, imagine that it is already available for your use. Hence, the code could be written as follows:

```
public static boolean everything1(IntBTNode node) {
    return (node == null)
        || (node.data == 1 && everything1(node.left) && everything1(root.right));
}
```

Recursive calls to `everything1` correspond to lines 2 and 3 of the description above.

Comment: but if the node is null, it will return true always, will it? should it be maybe (node != null) && (node.data == 1.... ?

Comment: @DamianLattenero No, using `||` is correct. if you do this, the program is never going to return `true`.

Comment: aaaaah, I see it now, nice answer :D, and even shorter.

Answer (score 2):

but before you call ·everything1·, i think you should determine IntBTNode node is null or not.

```
public static boolean everything1(IntBTNode node, int key) {
    if(node == null) return true;
    if(node.data != key){
        return false;
    }
    return everything1(node.left, key) && everything1(node.right, key);
}
```

Comment: well done, even works generally not only for 1, plus one here.